# Has anyone worked with performanceactive Custom Camera plugin for phoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have add the following custom camera plugin through ionic CLI however it cannot seem to find the getPicture method. Here is my controller

```
 .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory) {
$scope.takePhoto = function(){
  navigator.customCamera.getPicture(filename, function success(fileUri) {
      alert("File location: " + fileUri);
  }, function failure(error) {
      alert(error);
  }, {
      quality: 80,
      targetWidth: 120,
      targetHeight: 120
  });
};
```

I have not added any dependencies to my module as I would not know what to add I
have used ionic, however have never had experience adding a plugin into  my project.

This is the plugin I want to add:
https://github.com/performanceactive/phonegap-custom-camera-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.